# Android: Cannot replace bundle from a service on Restart

Tags: android, service, bundle, onresume

I am trying to pass some values by using a bundle through a pending intent to my activity from a service.  If the app is just started everything works fine but when the app is in resume mode, though my service receives new values from the remote server and put them in the pendingintent to pass to the activity, the activity shows the old values. Here is the code on service side:

```
    private void sendNotification(String wholemsg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    /* Do something to extract salesID and notificationmessage from wholemsg
    ....
    ....
    ....
    salesID=....
    notificationmessage=...
    ....
    */


    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("msg", notificationmessage);
    bundle.putString("strsalesID", salesID);    

    notificationIntent.replaceExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent,        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT+PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)

    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("AppV001 Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationmessage))
            .setContentText(notificationmessage);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

And this is onRestart method on my activity:

```
           @Override
        protected void onRestart() {

    super.onRestart();


    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
    try {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra("msg") && intent.hasExtra("strsalesID")) {
            String strmsgtitle = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
            salesID = intent.getStringExtra("strsalesID");
            titletext.setText(getString(R.string.str_ettitle) + salesID);
        } 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the salesID holds the previous value when the app comes back from hidden mode. It seems that the service cannot change the bundle of activity while it is hidden.

Many thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Depending on what launchMode you've specified for this activity in your manifest, you may need to override [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) to receive an updated `Intent` from the service.

Comment: Thanks for reaching back! I tried to use onNewIntent() but it does not fire the event. here is the manifest: <activity
            android:name="com.example.appv001.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was wrong with what my code and I want to post it here in case someone else faced the same problem. [acj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357055/acj) was right and there was a problem with my launch mode.  My original application manifest was this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appv001.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Since the launch mode wasn't declared the standard mode was taken automatically. We can have four launchMode[(look at this)](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode):

> The 'standard' is the default value. The four values fall into two
>   groups:
>
> - 'standard' and 'singleTop' can instantiate multiple activity instances and the instance will stay in the same task.
> - For 'singleTask' or 'singleInstance', the activity class uses the singleton pattern, and that instance will be the root activity of a
>     new task.

Since my activity had standard launch mode, when the service was calling it a new instance of the activity was created and the intent was passed to the this new activity. Therefore instead of invoking "onNewIntent()", the "onCreate" method was invoked, in the other words the "onNewIntent()" was never called to set the bundle and etc. I changed the activity manifest to this and set the launch mode to singleTask (android:launchMode="singleTask) and the problem just solved:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appv001.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I hope this helps someone else.